# Getting Child Items of SCCM 2012 Global Conditions using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I've been searching for DAYS and while I have a laundry list of a dozen different ways to MAKE Global Conditions in PowerShell, what I'm looking to figure out is if there is a better way of making an "Expression Tree" out of my Global Conditions from SCCM 2012 in PowerShell.

I have a small collection of Global Conditions I have defined for Application Requirements and some of them are based on combinations of other Global Conditions. e.g.

- Work Stations X64 (All Windows 7 SP1 - Windows 10 X64 Operating Systems)
- Servers X64 (All Windows Server 2008 R2 - 2016)

And a Global Condition based on the previous two

- All Systems X64 (Work Stations X64 OR Servers X64)

So using the `Get-CMGlobalCondition` Cmdlet I can get a list of all my Global Conditions I can also use the optional -Id, -Name, to get a specific Global Condition

The problem is that the only reference that each Global Condition object has for its children (Accessed via the SDMPackageXML property ) are

- AuthoringScopeId
- LogicalName

Neither of which work for the Id (Needs the CI_ID) or the Name (Needs the LocalizedDisplayName) of `Get-CMGlobalCondition`

Obviously I can write some code to just parse through the entirety of the Global Conditions collection over and over and build out my expression tree but I'd rather just do what I would do for any other Parent-Child based hierarchy of data and apply some old fashioned recursion to it but without the parent having a property for each child that easily passes to the Cmdlet I'm stuck with this way.

I'm not against using direct WQL if there's nothing in the PowerShell Cmdlets for SCCM.

Just in case anyone asks this is to go along with import scripts that update our UDI Wizard and it's associated .xml.app file (including translating Global Conditions from SCCM into Delivery Rules in UDI)

Comment: [SCCM MOdule](http://www.snowland.se/powershell/sccm-posh/)

Comment: A GC's UniqueID is equal to AuthoringScope/LogicalName which are found in the following nodes in the `SDMPackageXML`-xml: `$xml.SelectNodes("//GlobalExpression//GlobalExpression")`. You can use that to lookup the child GC and get the LocalizedDisplayName  (and their dependencies if any)

Comment: @RanadipDutta - Thanks for the link, (Seriously adding it to my collection of useful SCCM PowerShell Scripts) That being said, doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @FrodeF. - Yeah I can determine the parent child relationship using the SDMPackageXML it's just a tedious process. It seems a bit of a disconnect if all the object is going to return to indicate child relationships are NOT viable parameters for the Get-CMGlobalCondition cmdlet. Also from what I can determine playing around with the direct WQL, WMI returns even less information than the cmdlet does. I was REALLY hoping for the kind of easy parent child relationship properties like DOM and DirectoryInfo, Ah well guess coding wouldn't be as much fun if it was easy all the time

Comment: Doesn't wmi provide the same (can't test atm)? Remember to run `Get()` on the wmi-object first to get lazy properties like SDMPackageXML. Are you writing a function to list the tree for a single condition or are you going to list all (but add a tree/subnodes when they are linked)?

Comment: @FrodeF. - I had forgot about the Lazy properties for a moment (up till now the PS Cmdlet's have given me everything I've needed for other tasks) but SMS_GlobalCondition returns EXACTLY the same thing as the PS Cmdlet. The idea is to have the ability (like .NET's expression trees) to take an applications Requirement(s) and expand them out until you are down to the actual WMI/File/Registry queries. So said queries can be combined in much the same way Linq2<FillInTheDataSource> builds a select statement.

Comment: @FrodeF. - Coding the logic is not hard at all. It just makes me stop and wonder if I'm truly missing something when what is clearly a Parent/Children relationship is exposed in a way that blatantly lacks the ability to navigate up and down the "family" tree using simple properties